# Установить параметр checked на все checkbox

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть checkbox которые выводяться через цикл.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="subs<?=$item['id']?>" name="subs[]" value="<?=$item['email']?>" checked="">
```

По умолчанию они все checked. Сделал кнопку и хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку все checkbox снимались или ставились исходя из первичного состояния? 
не могу понять как реализовать со всеми checkbox

Comment: Не дубликат. Там снять, а тут инвертировать.

Comment: @duddeniska  добавил еще ответ без цикла `each`. Чтоб вы знали)

Comment: @Qwertiy переоткроем)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, лучше скажи: _без явного вызова each_ :)

Comment: @Grundy иди гуляй)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне срочно нужен модераторский ромб с банхаммером :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $(this).prop('checked', !checked);
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="button" value="clickme" />
```

Пробегаем элементы. Смотрим их <strike>чеканутость</strike> атрибут `checked`. Берем его и меняем на противоположный.

---

UPD. Говорят, `each` не обязателен. Так что можно написать даже вот так:

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop( "checked", function(i, prop) {
    return !prop;
  });
});
```

Comment: `each` - ненужен: [.prop( propertyName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function)

Comment: @Grundy добавил. сойдет?

Comment: вполне сойдет .